# On a BJT, is there a relationship between the base voltage and the Vcc voltage?

Tags: transistors, bjt

I just built a circuit that utilizes a BJT as a switch. It consisted of a voltage source connected to the base through a 100k ohm resistor. I grounded the emitter and connected a diode and a resistor in series on the collector terminal. The anode of the diode had a power supply connected to it. By my calculation, for a base current of 50 uA, I calculated they the voltage source must be 5.7 volts to have Vbe = 0.7 to have a collector/emitter current. However, I noticed that the current still flowed, by the LED being lit up,
for input voltage values much smaller than 5.7 V. I also noticed that as Vcc grew larger, less and less voltage was needed from the other power supply that was connected to the base to light up the LED.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxHAng.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Why do we still have a collector current when Vbb < 5.7 V. Also, is there a relationship between Vcc and Vb? I don’t understand why my base power supply needed less voltage to turn on the LED as Vcc grew.

Comment: Yes, there is a relationship. There are also voltage/current relationships for resistors and for LEDs and for voltage sources. Generally, we can predict what a small circuit does by writing down all the equations, and then using mathematical techniques for solving simultaneous equations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I just built a circuit that utilizes a BJT as a switch.

Whether a circuit acts as a switch depends on how it's configured.

You *wanted* the circuit to be a switch, but **you built a current source**. It's not a very precise current source, since its output current is highly dependent on the current gain of the transistor (\$\beta\$), and that parameter is subject to large process spread between the transistors even of the same type.

For "hard" switching applications, when you want the transistor to go from an "open" to a "short", the transistor must be configured as a **saturated switch**.

This means that the base current must be sufficient to bring the collector-emitter voltage down to Vce(sat).

The circuit you've built is indeed driving 50uA into the base, causing the transistor to conduct a few to a few dozen mA - it acts as a current source. You could remove the series LED resistor, replacing it with a short, and the current would not change much. That's because the transistor is not saturated.

To saturate the transistor, increase the base current until the C-E voltage is say <0.5V. At that point, the LED current will be determined entirely by the series resistance and the supply voltage (as long as the transistor is not thermally damaged).

> Why do we still have a collector current when Vbb < 5.7 V

Because a saturated switch requires on/off base drive. It's not some comparator circuit that detects when you're past a threshold and sharply turns on then.

> [...] is there a relationship between the base voltage and the Vcc voltage?

Yes!

The [Ebers-Moll model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipolar_junction_transistor#Theory_and_modeling) does a good job of describing this:

$$
I_E = I_{ES} \left( e^ \frac{V_{BE}}{V_T} - 1 \right),\\
I_C = \alpha_F \cdot I_E
$$

where \$I_{ES} \sim 10^{-13}\$ is the reverse saturation current of the base-emitter diode,  \$V_T \approx 26 \,\text{mV}\$ is the thermal voltage at junction temperature of 300K, and \$\alpha_F \approx 0.98\$ is the common base forward short-circuit current gain.

As you can see, the emitter current is an exponential function of the ratio of base-emitter voltage to the thermal voltage. It's not a very sharp transition, and *any* positive B-E voltage, even close to \$V_T\$, will produce some collector current, even if in the femtoampere level. Measuring such low currents requires utmost attention to cleanliness and measurement technique.

To have a sharp cut-off when the input voltage changes only slightly, you need a circuit that approximates a comparator - and has quite a bit of open-loop gain.

Typical implementation would be a long-tailed differential pair, with a suitable output stage. For example:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSUMwY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The transition is indeed quite sharp - note that the LED current scale is logarithmic:

[image: LED current vs. control voltage plot]

Q1-Q2 is the differential long-tailed pair, with R1 being the tail impedance. Q3-Q4 is the current mirror load for the pair. R2-R3 provides the 2.5V threshold voltage: the LED is OFF then the input is below this voltage, and ON when the input is above it. Q5 is the buffer stage, Q6-Q7 is the output stage. R5 sets the LED current.

For higher LED currents, e.g. if it was a relay and not a LED, Q7 would be 2N2222, since they have higher gain at currents above 100mA or so.

Answer (score 3):

> a voltage source connected to the base through a 100k ohm resistor...
> By my calculation, for a base current of 50 uA, I calculated the
> **voltage source must be 5.7 volts to have Vbe = 0.7** to have a
> collector/emitter current. However, I noticed that the current still
> flowed, by the LED being lit up, for input voltage values much smaller
> than 5.7 V.

You should think of the Base supply as a *current* source rather than a voltage source. The 100k resistor drops the difference between the power supply voltage and the Base voltage. If the supply voltage drops to eg. 5.0 V the voltage across the resistor reduces to ~4.3 V, and the current only drops by ~15%. This small change will only cause the Base voltage to drop by a small amount, insignificant compared to the voltage across the 100k resistor.

The relationship between Base-Emitter voltage and current is logarithmic over a wide range. For example in this graph from the [BC546](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/BC546.pdf) datasheet we see that a Base voltage change of only 0.2 V causes Collector current to change from 0.2 mA to 100 mA. This why when doing bias calculations we can often get away with assuming a Base voltage of 'approximately' 0.7 V.

[image]

It also shows why we need a resistor to set the Base current. Applying 0.7 V directly to the Base would require a very precise supply voltage to get an accurate Collector current. Furthermore the Base-Emitter voltage is temperature dependent with a slope of about -2 mV/°C, so as the transistor heats up the current increases dramatically, quickly leading to thermal runaway if Collector current is not limited externally.

Answer (score 2):

LEDs don't magically light up at a particular current threshold. Their brightness scales approx. linear with current. If the current through the LED is 100 µA instead of 1 mA, it will just look a bit dimmer. If the LED looks bright at 1 mA current, you will easily see that it is "on" with the naked eye at a mere 1 µA current.

As for the reduced base drive needed for larger collector supply: That is probably due to the **Early effect**. BJTs don't saturate very sharply like e.g. JFET. Instead they saturate rather softly (or not at all) due to the Early effect. So to get the same collector current, one can trade base-emitter voltage vs. collector-emitter voltage.

Answer (score 2):

You have a diode junction (base-emitter) in series with 100K. To a rough approximation, the base current is (Vs - 0.7)/100K for Vs >> 0.7V.

So with (say) a 3V source, the base current is ~23uA, and if the transistor has a \$\beta\$ of ~300 then the collector current could be as much as 7mA. That may or may not be limited by whatever resistor you put in series with the LED. 7mA is more than enough to brightly light a modern LED, depending on room lighting and so on you may be able to see uA levels of current.

If the transistor is not saturated (Vce is > 0.7V) then increasing the LED supply voltage will cause increased heating in the transistor which generally increases beta. Eg. [2N4401](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/2n4401-d.pdf): =

[image]

There's also another smallish effect from the Early voltage (maybe 30% increase in current for a Vce increase from 1V to 30V).

If the transistor is saturated then the increased voltage causes increased LED current more-or-less due to Ohms law and the series resistor associated with the LED.

If the LED supply voltage is decreased enough the transistor will saturate and eventually the LED will no longer be visibly illuminated because the LED requires some forward voltage to turn on.